# Can you optimize a simple for loop? - Java

Tags: java

My code is quite simple.

The customer has multiple accounts and I want to find the one that is the `accountNumber` passed in the method.

I know this is quite fast, but let's imagine the user has 5000 accounts.

Can you improve my code?

```
public Account getAccountFromCustomer(String customerID, String accountNumber) {
    List<Account> accounts = getAccountsFromCustomer(customerID);
    for(Account account : accounts) {
        if(account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)) {
            return account;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Even if it were 50,000 accounts, I doubt it would take any significant time to do that loop. Do you have a real, tangible problem you're currently debugging? If not, don't worry about it until you do.

Comment: The way to improve your code would be to have getAccountsFromCustomer use a HashMap instead of of a List.

Comment: You can optimize the syntax, using streams: `return getAccountsFromCustomer(customerID).stream().filter(a -> a.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)).findFirst().orElse(null);`.

Comment: @AndyTurner is it faster or fancier?

Comment: @user10717851 neither, necessarily. Merely more concise.

Comment: supposing that you are getting your customers from a database, this is something that can be done quite easily and performant with a single query.

Comment: this is no SQL. it's web service

Comment: Take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much you can do to speed that up, but then, you probably don't have to, either. It's going to be quite fast with any decent `List` implementation.

You could make `getAccountsFromCustomer` return a `Map` instead keyed by the account number. If it used a `HashMap`, for instance, looking something up by the account would be much better than looping through a list.

Comment: Returning a map doesn't help if you've got to construct the map each time you invoke `getAccountsFromCustomer(customerID)`. You'd still have to iterate all the accounts, and then you'd throw most of the map away. It only really helps if you're able to reuse the map.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Yes, absolutely, I was assuming reuse. If it's coming from a backend, better would be to have a `getCustomerAccount` accepting the customer ID **and** account number.